# Which one is good to use pivot table with foreing key or comma separated list of foreign key in one column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, performance

I am trying to elaborate in an easy way.

I have one table posts and another one is categories.

Now one post should have multiple categories and the same one category might be associated with multiple posts.

Come to my main question:

Scenario 1: Take another pivot table like post_categories with post_id(PK of posts table) and cateogory_id (PK of categories table)

Scenario 2: Take one column category_ids (varchar or text) on posts table and fill comma separated category ids in that.

Anybody who plays around any one of this case and Which one is good to use for it comes to performance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: This one exactly well explained. Thanks Nigel